# TSQL list of business rules in MDS

Tags: t-sql, powerbi, master-data-services

I need help with querying my business rules in SQL!

I have created couple of business rules in MDS web service to validate my master data and found out that 2 % of my data is not complying with the rules. Now I have created a SQL subscription view to report on the invalid data in PowerBI. In my PowerBI report I need to tell the business user why the data is invalid but I cannot since the subscription view only tells where the data is invalid but not why the data is invalid. So I need to know how I might query my business rules from MDS database in SQL and map it with my PowerBI data model. Is there a way to query the list of business rules from MDS database?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there are multiple ways to go about this. Here are some solutions, pls choose one that suits your scenario.

## 1. SQL - List of all Business Rules

The following query will retrieve the list of all Active Business Rules created in MDS.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM [MDM].[mdm].[viw_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_BUSINESSRULES]
  WHERE Model_Name = 'YourModelName'
  AND BusinessRule_StatusName = 'Active'
```

You can, of course, further filter by `Entity_Name`, etc.
The important columns in your case are going to be:

- `[BusinessRule_Name]`
- `[BusinessRule_Description]`
- `[BusinessRule_RuleConditionText]`
- `[BusinessRule_RuleActionText]`

**Note:** The challenge in your scenario, I think, is going to be that the Subscription View of the entity does not have IDs of the exact Business Rules that failed. So I'm not sure how you'll tie these 2 together (failing Rows -> List of Business Rules). Also remember that each row may have more than 1 business rule that failed.

## 2. using View `viw_SYSTEM_USER_VALIDATION`

This is a view that has a historical list of all business rules (+row info) that failed. You may use the view in this way:

```sql
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ValidationIssue_ID, Version_ID, VersionName, Model_ID, ModelName, Entity_ID, EntityName, Hierarchy_ID, HierarchyName, Member_ID, MemberCode, MemberType_ID, MemberType, ConditionText, ActionText, BusinessRuleID, BusinessRuleName, PriorityRank, DateCreated, NotificationStatus_ID, NotificationStatus
FROM [MDM].[mdm].[viw_SYSTEM_USER_VALIDATION]
 WHERE --CAST(DateCreated as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) AND
    ModelName = 'YourModelName'
    --AND EntityName IN ('Entity_1','Entity_2') -- Use this to Filter on specific Entities
```

Here, use the columns `Model_ID`, `Entity_ID` and `Member_ID`/`MemberCode` to identify the specific model, entity & row that failed.

Columns `BusinessRuleName`, `ConditionText` & `ActionText` will give your users additional info on the Business Rule that failed.

**Note:**

- One issue with using this view is that even though, let's say, your failure condition was resolved the next day by the user, the view will still show that on a certain date, a validation had failed. (via column `DateCreated`).
- Also note that the same failed data row will appear multiple times here if multiple Business Rules on the same row failed validation (there will be different BusinessRuleID/Name, etc). Just something to take note of.
- Similarly, the same row may appear multiple times if it has failed again & again at different times. To workaround this, and if your final report can do with that, add a WHERE clause on the DateCreated column so that you only get to see any row that Failed today. The commented out line of code `<--CAST(DateCreated as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) AND>` does the same. If you can't use that, just make sure the data row are distinct. However, if you do this, remember that if something Failed yesterday (and is still in the Failed status), it may not show up.

My suggestion would be to use a slightly modified version of Solution #2:

Get the list of Failed Rows from your Subscription View (the data row's ValidationStatus is actually **still** *'Failed'*), then JOIN with `viw_SYSTEM_USER_VALIDATION` making sure that you only select the row with `MAX(DateCreated)` value (of course for the same data row AND Business Rule).

Best of luck and if you find anything else while solving this issue, do share your learning here with all of us.

Lastly, if you found this useful, pls remember to Mark it as the Answer :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the input. I succeeded with querying my business rules but the result of the second query: system_user_validation was empty? is it because the data is temporarily stored in this view ? My store procedure contains the result. so how am I going to query the result of the validationissue either from the view which is currently empty or save the result of the temp table in my store procedure into a new table.